# How to get rid of HTTP 302 status code while reading a page in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, http-status-code-302, lwp-useragent

I am trying to fetch the content of a webpage which requires authentication using LWP::UserAgent. However I am getting status as 302 Found and "The document has moved here

I have added `push @{ $uagent->requests_redirectable }, 'GET';` statement but no help.

Below is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $userid = "iamuser";
my $password = "thisispassword";
my $url = "http://some_website-requires-authentication";

my $uagent = new LWP::UserAgent();
push @{ $uagent->requests_redirectable }, 'GET';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET=>"$url");
$req->authorization_basic($userid,$password);

my $response = $uagent->request($req);
print $response->status_line, "\n";
print $response->headers->as_string;
```

Output:

```
302 Found
Cache-Control: no-store
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Wed, 11 Aug 2018 04:43:10 GMT
Location: HTTP://my_url.website.com/page/bag
Server: website
Content-Length: 239
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Client-Date: Wed, 11 0 04:43:11 GMT
Client-Peer: 
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /CGB/ST=Larer Urban/L=Reds/O=COKPO CB Insurabce/CN=DO A  Secure SDL
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=UKBopp Drive/O=te Incorporated/OU=COPPER/CN=hula.website.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: AES128-SHA
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
Client-Warning: Redirect loop detected (max_redirect = 7)
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=91
Set-Cookie: blablabla
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Title: 302 Found
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Need help on what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get redirects by default, no need to add it.  Possibly you are hitting the max_redirect limit (default 7)?  Look at the response and see if it actually is redirecting?

Comment: You do understand that what you are doing is what you would do for a very few websites that use http header based authentication, and it won't work for a more common website that has a login form, correct?

Comment: @ysth Thanks.  The response says the document has moved here along with 302 status code, even removing $uagent ->request_redirectable not helping.

Comment: Please provide the response headers (`$response->headers->as_string`). Feel free to obfuscate private info (replace private words with other words), but don't remove anything

Comment: @ikegami It says Authorization: Basic Ui0ow00d0dbu3nyKljdidimd==
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.13

Comment: When I said look at the response, I didn't mean the final content.  Try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $response;`. (instead of or before calling ->content)

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast, There's no way the command I gave you returned what you said it did --you printed `$req->headers->as_string` instead of `$response->headers->as_string`--  and there's no way the command ysth gave returned (just) what said it did. We got lucky, and you included enough in the latter, though.

Comment: Tip: `"$url"` should be `$url`. Converting strings to strings is a useless waste

Comment: Tip: `push @{ $uagent->requests_redirectable }, 'GET';` is useless. `GET` (and `HEAD`) are already in that array.

Comment: Tip: The indirect method call syntax is problematic and discouraged. Replace `new LWP::UserAgent(...)` with `LWP::UserAgent->new(...)`

Answer (score 1):

One of the headers you received was

```
Client-Warning: Redirect loop detected (max_redirect = 7)
```

LWP detected that it was in an endless chain of redirects, and aborted. The web site probably relies on the cookies it provides being returned, but you didn't create a cookie jar for the agent to allow it to do that.

Replace

```
my $uagent = LWP::UserAgent->new();
```

with

```
my $uagent = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => {} );
```